# Using Vite to bundle modules without renaming classes

Tags: gradle, vite, bundler

I am working with a JavaScript API that organizes files into modules, each containing classes and helper functions. We've been using Gradle to bundle these files into a single 'core.js' file, which users include in their application by specifying the URL as a script tag in their HTML file. However, we are running into the issue that our classes cannot be loaded directly as modules into ES6 or CommonJS files.

We want to change to Vite for bundling in order to achieve these three bundling scenarios:

1. Bundle files into one core.js file with no exports
2. Bundle files into CommonJS modules
3. Bundle files into ES6 modules

CommonJS and ES6 modules are covered in the Vite documentation. The obstical I don't know how to tackle is bundling the classes into one core.js file with no exports and additionally without renaming the classes, ie. I don't want to rename ClassOne to be F.

Is there a way to achieve this specific bundling process using Vite? Specifically, how to configure the rollup to not change class names and to not use exports?